# Bind each row of NSTableView to separate property of object?

Tags: cocoa, bind, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, kvc

I have a main NSArrayController bound to an NSTableView with each row containing an instance of MyObject. MyObject has about 30 properties, but the NSTableView only has 5 columns (to show the most important properties). When a row (or more) is selected I have another NSTableView (a detail view) which shows all the properties, one per row. The detail table has two columns, one for the property name and one for the property value.

I have this working right now but my detail NSTableView uses a data source rather than bindings. This works fine as long as I notify my detail controller (which manages the data source) of a change in the main selection so that it can reload the detail table.

While it is easy to detect a change in selection, it is harder to detect a change in one of the properties of a selected object. I see elsewhere on StackOverflow, that one way to do this is to have a dummy property and use keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey. Does this work well performance-wise?

Is there some other/better way to build my detail NSTableView/NSArrayController so that each row represents one property of the selected objects on the main NSTableView/NSArrayController? I'd like to use bindings if possible.

Comment: selected object**s**? You can detect changes in properties by observing them.